# Make comparison of folders more efficient by opening one subfolder one at a time

Tags: python, loops, filesystems, glob, os.path

I am comparing two folders containing images (Folder A and Folder B) for the purpose of identifying duplicates in Folder B. The comparison method is OpenCV's SIFT.

My original code stored the SIFT feature analysis for each image in a dictionary, and this worked until I tried to compare two very large folders which froze the computer (presumably because there was too much data being stored in the dictionaries).

I rewrote the code with loops so that only one subfolder in Folder B is analyzed at a time.  **The problem: The code works but takes a long time. I am looking for suggestions on how to reorder the nested elements to make the code run faster.**

Here is what I have tried: I've tried placing the code that reads the SIFT values of Folder A only once, but if I put it outside the loop (ie. before the line `for folder in glob.glob...`), the variable **desc_1** is empty and I get empty spreadsheets as a result.  I've also tried putting the block beginning with `for a in glob.iglob` and the block beginning with `for b in glob.iglob` on the same level of indentation within the `for folder in glob.glob` loop, but again, an empty spreadsheet at the end.

I also tried to make the analysis of Folder A the first step in the loop, but this results in the spreadsheet being overwritten each time the loops runs.

```
#Based on the tutorial provided by Sergio Canu (pysource) - https://pysource.com/2018/07/20/find-similarities-between-two-images-with-opencv-and-python/

from __future__ import division

import cv2
import os, os.path


import numpy as np
import glob
import pandas as pd

    # Sift and Flann
sift = cv2.SIFT_create()

index_params = dict(algorithm=0, trees=5)
search_params = dict()
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
 

Match = []
Match2 = []
listOfSimilarities = []
countInner = 0
countOuter = 0

 
#Identify the images

folder1 = "/home/oem/Desktop/Folder1/**"

folder1_count = sum(len(files) for _,_, files in os.walk('/home/oem/Desktop/Folder1/'))

folder2_count = sum(len(files) for _,_, files in os.walk('/home/oem/Desktop/_test'))

print(folder1_count)
print(folder2_count)

extensionsOnly = ('.jpeg','.jpg','.png','.tif','.tiff','.gif')

#Make a dictionary representing SIFT readings of each photo in folder one

for folder in glob.glob(r"/home/oem/Desktop/_test/*/",recursive=True):
        folderPrint = folder.split(os.sep)[-2]
        folder = folder + "**"
        
        print(folderPrint)

        siftOut1 = {}

        for a in glob.iglob(folder1,recursive=True):

            if not a.lower().endswith(extensionsOnly):

                continue

            image1 = cv2.imread(a)

            kp_1, desc_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(image1, None)

            siftOut1[a]=(kp_1,desc_1)

            siftOut2 = {}

            for b in glob.iglob(folder,recursive=True):
                

                if not b.lower().endswith(extensionsOnly):

                    continue

                image2 = cv2.imread(b)

                kp_2, desc_2 = sift.detectAndCompute(image2, None)

                siftOut2[b]=(kp_2,desc_2)

                countOuter += 1

                
                    #fill the variable with the second sift value in the dictionary
                    #calculate the matches between the two sift analyses, and store in variable 'matches'

                matches = flann.knnMatch(desc_1, desc_2, k=2)

                good_points = []
                #for every match, check that the distance meets a certain threshold (lower distance suggests a higher quality match).  Add matches which meet this threshold to the list good_points
                for m, n in matches:
                    if m.distance < 0.6*n.distance:
                        good_points.append(m)
                        # print(m)
                #calculate which photo has the highest number of key points, and store in the variable 'number_keypoints'
                number_keypoints = 0
                if len(kp_1) >= len(kp_2):
                    number_keypoints = len(kp_1)
                else:
                    number_keypoints = len(kp_2)
                #calculate the percentage to which the photos are similar by dividing the good points by the keypoints
                percentage_similarity = int(float(len(good_points)) / number_keypoints * 100)
                # If the photo matches, add to the list Match, Match2 and the list of Similarities.  

                if percentage_similarity > 16:
                    # print(a)
                    Match.append(a)
                    Match2.append(b)
                    listOfSimilarities.append(percentage_similarity)

            #This takes the three lists and places them side-by-side in a dataframe

        zippedList = list(zip(Match,Match2, listOfSimilarities))

        dfObj = pd.DataFrame(zippedList, columns = ['Original', 'Title', 'listofSimilarities' ])

        dfObj.to_csv(r"/home/oem/Desktop/Results2/" + folderPrint +".csv")

        Match = []

        Match2 = []

        zippedList = []
```

As per request, I have included a minimal reproducible example:

```
import time
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os

    # Sift and Flann
    
startTime = time.time()
 
#Identify the images

folder1 = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\folder1\\**"

Match = []

for folder2 in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\folder2\*\\",recursive=True):

        for a in glob.iglob(folder1,recursive=True):

            h1 = os.path.getsize(a)
            
            for b in glob.iglob(folder2,recursive=True):
                
                h2 = os.path.getsize(b)
                
                if h1 >= h2:
                    
                   Match.append(a)

        dfObj = pd.DataFrame(Match)

        dfObj.to_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Results2\\"+ folder2.split(os.sep)[-2] + ".csv")

        Match = []
        

executionTime = (time.time() - startTime)
print('Execution time in seconds: ' + str(executionTime))
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-based_image_retrieval -- so, _what_ exactly is the problem, in one short sentence? and why is that a "problem", i.e. challenging? -- please review [mre]. you present 120 lines of code that contains no structure. identify self-contained pieces of code and refactor into functions.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Christoph Rackwitz - have created a minimal reproducible example and bolded my question.

Comment: so... you get the size of the same files repeatedly, and you repeatedly _glob_, which takes time to calculate. perhaps do that once, stick the values (as path-size tuples) in a list or something. -- I'm outta here. not my area of interest. at least we seem to have established (have we?) that the time taken isn't due to OpenCV (which does cost all on its own) but due to enumerating your directories. I think the pandas stuff also doesn't contribute

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to identify **files of the same size**, you could just stick all the paths in a *dictionary* that is indexed by file size.

```py
import collections

# this lambda creates a new empty list for any key that doesn't already exist
by_size = collections.defaultdict(lambda: [])

for path in all_your_files:
    size = os.path.getsize(path)
    by_size[size].append(path)

same_size = {
    size: paths
    for (size, paths) in by_size.items()
    if len(paths) > 1
}
```

Same can be done using cryptographic hashes (MD5, SHAs, ...).

If you're really going for **content comparison**, you'll need to learn about [Content-based image retrieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-based_image_retrieval)
.

The usual approach is to have a database (simple numpy array) of "feature vectors", one feature vector per picture. In that database you can do nearest-neighbor queries. If the feature vector of a query image has a nearest neighbor that is close enough, it might be similar.